# Create array of type base class

Tags: java, arrays, class

Title not very suggestive, please advise for a better one.

The example can be found in the oca-java-se O'Reilly.

I have a base class

```
public class Thing{
   public int thingOne;
   public int thingTwo;
}
```

In main

```
class MyMain{
public static void main (String[] args){
    Thing[] ta;

    // how do I initialize this array

    // is there a tricky way to access elements rather than ta[0] ??

  }
}
```

I am confused. I guess the lesson is how to create an array of type base class, initialize it and access elements from it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is to initialize your array object with a given length and the just iterate to fill it with elements. A simple example of this is the following:

```
public class ArrayTest {

    public static class Thing  {

        private int thingOne;
         public int getThingOne() { return thingOne; }
         public void setThingOne(int thingOne) { this.thingOne = thingOne; }

         private int thingTwo;
         public int getThingTwo() { return thingTwo; }
         public void setThingTwo(int thingTwo) { this.thingTwo = thingTwo; }

         @Override
         public String toString() {
             return "Thing{" +
              "thingOne=" + thingOne +
              ", thingTwo=" + thingTwo +
              '}';
         }

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Thing[] array = new Thing[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            Thing thing = new Thing();
            thing.setThingTwo(new Random().nextInt(10));
            thing.setThingTwo(new Random().nextInt(10));
            array[i] = thing;
        }

        Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you. Your example made sense the most of it. I appreciate you guessing what I meant. I extracted this,

Comment: it was really good that you've added the getters and setter and the toString. I realised afterwards I need those. I was expecting to be offered an add() method, since this is an array.

Comment: @Kinfol thanks! If you feel that my answered covered your question make sure to upvote it and make it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `public class Thing(){` is wrong. It should be `public class Thing{`

> how do I initialize this array

There are many ways to initialize the array e.g.

```
class Thing {
    public int thingOne;
    public int thingTwo;
}

class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // First way
        Thing[] ta1 = new Thing[] {};

        // Also
        Thing[] ta2 = new Thing[] { new Thing(), new Thing() };

        // Using a loop
        Thing[] ta3 = new Thing[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < ta3.length; i++)
            ta3[i] = new Thing();
    }
}
```

> is there a tricky way to access elements rather than ta[0]

If you want to access an element using its index value, there is no other way. However, if you do need to access elements using index values, there are ways e.g.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Thing {
    public int thingOne;
    public int thingTwo;
}

public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thing[] ta = new Thing[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < ta.length; i++)
            ta[i] = new Thing();

        // Accessing the elements without index value
        for (Thing t : ta) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }

        // Another way
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ta));

        // Also
        Arrays.stream(ta).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```